# concat vs spread syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm working a codebase where it has lots of inconsistency as it has been worked on by multiple different person.

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([ action.text ])
   default:
      return state
   }
}
```

Instead of doing concat can I use spread syntax instead?

`return [...state, action.text]`

Comment: You should be able to. Did it break when you tried it or something?

Comment: I would use the spread syntax, because it was developed for your needs. It is also the more clean and modern way.

Comment: @Ryan I'm on mobile, I haven't test it, I want to know the alternative of concat, I want to standardize the code.

Comment: @JennyMok: Well, it’d be one spread instead of two, as in `[...state, action.text]`, but I’m not sure why you’d ask this now if you can’t try it anyway. Just wait until you’re off mobile and experiment ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Ryan action is object right? what is the result of `[...state, action.text]`?

Comment: I would choose spread syntax.

Comment: @JennyMok: The same as the result of `state.concat([action.text])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spread operator vs array.concat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Both, spread syntax and Array.prototype.concat() dont mutate the state, thus respecting the second rule of redux

> State is read-only