# Javascript: Merge Two Arrays of Objects, Only If Not Duplicate (Based on Specified Object Key)

Tags: javascript, arrays

## Background

Say I have an initial array of objects:

```
var initialData = [
    {
        'ID': 1,
        'FirstName': 'Sally'
    },
    {
        'ID': 2,
        'FirstName': 'Jim'
    },
    {
        'ID': 3,
        'FirstName': 'Bob'
    }
];
```

I then get new data (another array of objects):

```
var newData = [
    {
        'ID': 2,
        'FirstName': 'Jim'
    },
    {
        'ID': 4,
        'FirstName': 'Tom'
    },
    {
        'ID': 5,
        'FirstName': 'George'
    }
];
```

## Goal

I want to merge the new data into initial data. However, I don't want to overwrite any objects in the initial data array. I just want to add in objects that weren't already there.

I know the objects are duplicates based on their `'ID'` key.

## What I've Tried

I know I can do this by looping through the new data, checking to see if it exists in the initial data, and if not, pushing into initial data.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = newData.length; i < l; i++  ) {

    if ( ! key_exists( newData[i].key, initialData ) ) {  // key_exists() is a function that uses .filter() to test.

        initialData.push( newData[i] );

    }


}
```

I'm concerned about performance, though. I know there are lots of new ES6 ways of manipulating arrays, so I'm hoping someone has a better idea.

## Question

What is the best way (best as in best performance) of merging the new data into the initial data, while ignoring duplicates in new data?

Comment: This isn't really duplicate question, because in that question, when there are two duplicate objects, they want to be merged. In my case, when there are duplicate objects, I want to drop the new one.

Comment: Are you assured any ordering with respect to IDs? That could reduce looping as you could optimize the search and make decisions based on the `id` of the current object. Even if not, a simple ordering can be applied prior to looping.

Comment: @Nick, I am not assured ordering. 99% of the time, the order will be different.

Comment: I seem to have flagged the wrong ones and I have to nip away so I voted to reopen, but this is **definitely** ground that's been thoroughly covered in previous questions. The usual solution is to build a Map (or object-as-map). I just don't have an example to hand and have to disappear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I did look at existing questions before I posted, but all the ones I found just ended up merging the duplicate objects, rather than dropping if duplicate. I may have missed it, though. Apologies if that is the case, and thanks for helping flag things.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can create a set of IDs from `initialData` and this will make "check if ID is already in initial data" faster - O(1):

```js
var initialData = [{
    'ID': 1,
    'FirstName': 'Sally'
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'FirstName': 'Jim'
  },
  {
    'ID': 3,
    'FirstName': 'Bob'
  }
];

var newData = [{
    'ID': 2,
    'FirstName': 'Jim'
  },
  {
    'ID': 4,
    'FirstName': 'Tom'
  },
  {
    'ID': 5,
    'FirstName': 'George'
  }
];

var ids = new Set(initialData.map(d => d.ID));
var merged = [...initialData, ...newData.filter(d => !ids.has(d.ID))];

console.log(merged);
```

The final runtime of this approach is *O(n + m)*.

If you want to be slightly more efficient, you can consider looping through `newData` and pushing any new elements to the final result array manually (instead of using `filter` and the spread operator).

Comment: Nit: Another possible performance improvement would be using concat instead of spreading. There is info that concat is a little bit faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question about your answer, what is the reason for creating a `Set` rather than an `Array` of the `ids`?

Comment: @AndyMercer With a `Set`, the check for whether or not an ID is in it (`ids.has(d.ID)`) is constant time. Whereas in an array, it would be linear time (`includes` or `filter` will have to go through each element in the list). This advantage of `Set` is essential in this case to improve efficiency.

Comment: Nice succinct answer, but I had a time of this working out why it was not combining the data!
I found I had to `return` the callback on the filter
`var ids = new Set(initialData.map(d => d.ID));
var merged = [...initialData, ...newData.filter(d => return !ids.has(d.ID))];
console.log(merged);
`

Comment: @Beerswiller that should not be necessary as in arrow functions when you don't use the  curly braces, the return is implied: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Comment: @slider thanks for the heads up on the `{ }`. The code I'm working on has a slightly different flow and my merged array was missing all the newData until I returned the filter arrow function, as my code had braces! Always learning.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you are interested on performance, you could think on changing your `initialData` structure to something like this:

```
var initialData = {
    "1": {'FirstName': 'Sally'},
    "2": {'FirstName': 'Jim'},
    "3": {'FirstName': 'Bob'}
};
```

In other words, we use the IDs as the keys of an object, this will give you `O(1)` on access the data, and `O(1)` in the exists test. You can get this structure using the next approach with [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var initialData = [
    {'ID': 1, 'FirstName': 'Sally'},
    {'ID': 2, 'FirstName': 'Jim'},
    {'ID': 3, 'FirstName': 'Bob'}
];

let newInitialData = initialData.reduce((res, {ID, FirstName}) =>
{
    res[ID] = {FirstName : FirstName};
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(newInitialData);
```

Using this new structure, you can make a `O(n)` algorithm to insert the new data that is not already there:

```js
var initialData = {
    "1": {'FirstName': 'Sally'},
    "2": {'FirstName': 'Jim'},
    "3": {'FirstName': 'Bob'}
};

var newData = [
    {'ID': 2, 'FirstName': 'Jim'},
    {'ID': 4, 'FirstName': 'Tom'},
    {'ID': 5, 'FirstName': 'George'}
];

newData.forEach(({ID, FirstName}) =>
{
    initialData[ID] = initialData[ID] || {FirstName: FirstName};
});

console.log(initialData);
```

Comment: I like this, but I'm not sure how it would impact the sorting that I'm doing (which is out of scope for the initial question). I resort relatively frequently using `Array.sort()`, which wouldn't work (I think) if I mutate the array into an object.

Comment: Objects can't be sorted, you will have to convert it again to an array before sorting. Like a general rule, your data structure should be optimized for the type of operations you are using more often on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alternative solution proposed by @slider in the accepted answer, would be something like this:

```js
const oldData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Mike' },
];

const newData = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Rick' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Jim' },
];

const usersMap = new Map();

oldData.forEach(user => usersMap.set(user.id, user));

newData.forEach(user => {
  const exists = usersMap.has(user.id);
  
  if (!exists) {
    usersMap.set(user.id, user);
  }
})

usersMap.forEach(user => console.log(user))
```