# Merge multiple array of objects based on a key

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I need to merge a list of array of objects by a key. I tried to find materials online but ended up only on merging 2 array of objects.

But I have multiple array of objects in an array.

```
response = [
    [
        {
            "topic": "Topic 1",
            "avgwk38": 5
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 2",
            "avgwk38": 86
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 3",
            "avgwk38": 6
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "topic": "Topic 1",
            "avgwk39": 25
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 2",
            "avgwk39": 32
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 3",
            "avgwk39": 4
        }
    ]
]
```

Here is my expected result.

```
[
    {
        "topic": "Topic 1",
        "avgwk38": 5,
        "avgwk39": 25
    },
    {
        "topic": "Topic 2",
        "avgwk38": 86,
        "avgwk39": 32
    },
    {
        "topic": "Topic 3",
        "avgwk38": 6,
        "avgwk39": 4
    }
]
```

Please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Merge Two Arrays of Objects, Only If Not Duplicate (Based on Specified Object Key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134156/javascript-merge-two-arrays-of-objects-only-if-not-duplicate-based-on-specifi)

Comment: You are going to merge objects based on same `topic` key value/

Comment: @NullDev I think the solution provided is limited to 2 arrays (old and new array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten your array and reduce values.

```js
response.flat().reduce((acc, value) => {
  let existingValueIndex = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.topic === value.topic);
  if (existingValueIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({ ...value });
    return acc;
  }

  acc[existingValueIndex] = {
    ...acc[existingValueIndex],
    ...value,
  };
  return acc;
}, []);
```

It's not really efficient if you have big arrays.
You can also use a `Set` to keep track on Topic names and prevent searching in the array for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you @PAG this is working like a charm. I have only small arrays, as this is a monthly view with each week's average value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of solving this, 
Making an object of topics with a unique `topic`, which contains the properties of each topic item.

Finally using `Object.values()` to make this an array.

```js
const response = [
    [
        {
            "topic": "Topic 1",
            "avgwk38": 5
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 2",
            "avgwk38": 86
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 3",
            "avgwk38": 6
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "topic": "Topic 1",
            "avgwk39": 25
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 2",
            "avgwk39": 32
        },
        {
            "topic": "Topic 3",
            "avgwk39": 4
        }
    ]
]

const obj = response.flat().reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(!acc[curr.topic]) {
    acc[curr.topic] = {
      ...curr
    }
  } else {
    acc[curr.topic] = {
      ...acc[curr.topic],
      ...curr
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks mate @zb22 . Spread operator acts as a super power to JS