# What does the spread operator in ES6 convert to in older JavaScript? Is it costlier than array.concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to concat two arrays in JavaScript so I wanted to know if the ES6 spread operator `...` is costlier than `array.concat`?

Does that mean we should use the `...` syntax wisely and only when utmost needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spread operator vs array.concat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat)

Comment: Mandatory link to [Eric Lippert on performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spread Syntax ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)

Answer (score 2):

```
let arrayVar = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [...arrayVar, 4];
```

is equivalent to

```
var arrayVar = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [].concat(arrayVar, [4]);
```

per https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Your second example could also be written as`var array2 = arrayVar.concat([4]);`.

Comment: @EdLucas true, I just transcribed the output that babeljs.io provided for the given input.

Comment: @EdLucas in all honesty, it's probably even more accurate as `[].concat(arrayVar, 4)`. Although you get the same result in the end, so it hardly matters. I wouldn't be surprised if the exact same steps are taken in either case.