# Is there any difference between js concat function and spread operator merging/inserting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert, concatenation

I am wondering if there is any difference between these two methods to push to array in javascript knowing that they both will create new array.

```
const arr0 = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
const arr1 = arr0.concat(obj4);    // method 1
const arr2 = [...arr0, obj4];      // method 2
```

Comment: They both work fine, but first method is more efficient

Comment: It will make a difference if `obj4` is an array

Comment: @CertainPerformance is there any reference i can check ? Thanks

Comment: @adiga right, it will insert whole array as one element.

Answer (score 1):

a=[1]
`a.concat([2,3])` will give [1,2,3] whereas `[...a,[2,3]]` gives `[1,[2,3]]`.
For more info checkout this answer ([spread operator vs array.concat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat))