# JavaScript - Combining an array with an existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to combine my two array, but move only the object.

I have an array called `parentArr` that I am attempting to combine with `growthArr`. When using the `.push()` method it is returning `parentArr` as an array inside of `growthArr`. I am attempting to combine the objects from `parentArr` and not have it nested inside of an array.

Here is an example of what is happening:

```js
let growthArr = [
    {
     name: 'online stores',
      parent: 'high'
    }, {
       name: 'retail stores',
      parent: 'low'
     }, {
       name: 'walk in',
      parent: 'high'
    }
    ]
    
    
    let parentArr = [
    {
        id: 'low',
        color: '#fafafa'
    }, {
        id: 'med-low',
        color: '#B62721'
     }, {
        id: 'med',
        color: '#FF5733'
    }, {
        id: 'med-high',
        color: '#FF33FC'
    }, {
        id: 'high',
        color: '#33FF64'
    }
    ]
    
    
    growthArr.push(parentArr)
    
    
    console.log(growthArr)
```

To work around this, I've tried doing `growthArr.push.apply(parentArr)` but by doing this my `parentArr` does not show at all.

Here is my expected outcome, an array with both the objects in `growthArr` and `parentArr`

```
[
  {
    "name": "online stores",
    "parent": "high"
  },
  {
    "name": "retail stores",
    "parent": "low"
  },
  {
    "name": "walk in",
    "parent": "high"
  },
    {
      "id": "low",
      "color": "#fafafa"
    },
    {
      "id": "med-low",
      "color": "#B62721"
    },
    {
      "id": "med",
      "color": "#FF5733"
    },
    {
      "id": "med-high",
      "color": "#FF33FC"
    },
    {
      "id": "high",
      "color": "#33FF64"
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `...` syntax with `.push()`

```
growthArr.push(...parentArr)
```

---

This works because `.push()` takes any number of arguments, and pushes them all into the targeted array.

***Note:*** This mutates the original array without creating a new one and overwriting it. This can be important if there are other references to the array that need to observe the mutation.

---

FYI, your attempt would have worked:

```
growthArr.push.apply(parentArr)
```

Except that `.apply` expects the first argument to be the `this` value (the targeted array). So you'd need this:

```
growthArr.push.apply(growthArr, parentArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

`concat` is what you want to use.

```js
let growthArr = [{
 name: 'online stores',
  parent: 'high'
}, {
   name: 'retail stores',
  parent: 'low'
 }, {
   name: 'walk in',
  parent: 'high'
}]
    
    
let parentArr = [{
    id: 'low',
    color: '#fafafa'
}, {
    id: 'med-low',
    color: '#B62721'
 }, {
    id: 'med',
    color: '#FF5733'
}, {
    id: 'med-high',
    color: '#FF33FC'
}, {
    id: 'high',
    color: '#33FF64'
}]

console.log(
  growthArr.concat(parentArr)
)
```

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat) has some general guidelines when using rest spread vs concat

Answer (score 2):

Use `...array` for the values of an array.

```js
let growthArr = [{
  name: 'online stores',
  parent: 'high'
}, {
  name: 'retail stores',
  parent: 'low'
}, {
  name: 'walk in',
  parent: 'high'
}];

let parentArr = [{
  id: 'low',
  color: '#fafafa'
}, {
  id: 'med-low',
  color: '#B62721'
}, {
  id: 'med',
  color: '#FF5733'
}, {
  id: 'med-high',
  color: '#FF33FC'
}, {
  id: 'high',
  color: '#33FF64'
}];

growthArr = [...growthArr, ...parentArr];

console.log(growthArr);
```

Comment: concat is better here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.concat`. `parentArr.concat(growthArr)`

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to use **concat** instead of push
```

```js
let growthArr = [
    {
     name: 'online stores',
      parent: 'high'
    }, {
       name: 'retail stores',
      parent: 'low'
     }, {
       name: 'walk in',
      parent: 'high'
    }
    ]
    
    
    let parentArr = [
    {
        id: 'low',
        color: '#fafafa'
    }, {
        id: 'med-low',
        color: '#B62721'
     }, {
        id: 'med',
        color: '#FF5733'
    }, {
        id: 'med-high',
        color: '#FF33FC'
    }, {
        id: 'high',
        color: '#33FF64'
    }
    ]

   console.info(growthArr.concat(parentArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parentArr.concat(growthArr)`.
JS can be as simple as that!

Comment: Just like all the other answers that gave the same solution, you're not mutating the original array. You'd need to overwrite the original reference, and potentially all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use array concat() method. So the syntax would be

```
parentArr.concat(growthArr);
```

Comment: `.concat()` doesn't mutate the original array.

Comment: In that case you can simply go with spread operator @slappy

Answer (score 0):

All you need for this is the handy [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const
  growthArr = getGrowthArr(),
  parentArr = getParentArr();
growthArr.push(...parentArr);

console.log(growthArr);

function getGrowthArr() {
  return [{
    name: 'online stores',
    parent: 'high'
  }, {
    name: 'retail stores',
    parent: 'low'
  }, {
    name: 'walk in',
    parent: 'high'
  }];
}

function getParentArr() {
  return [{
    id: 'low',
    color: '#fafafa'
  }, {
    id: 'med-low',
    color: '#B62721'
  }, {
    id: 'med',
    color: '#FF5733'
  }, {
    id: 'med-high',
    color: '#FF33FC'
  }, {
    id: 'high',
    color: '#33FF64'
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with destructuring in es6 while creating a new array:

```
const combined = [...growthArr, ...parentArr];
```