# How to move multiple elements in an array from one position to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with 8 elements. How do I move the last 4 elements to the front?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using splice. But It is a bit confusing, also tried to use pushing new items and then unshifting them, but only 1 element moves to the start, no idea how to move more than one. (I am currently learning about Arrays so no prior knowledge).

Comment: Both slice and splice can move more than one item at a time

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combined with [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const result = arr.slice(4).concat(arr.slice(0, 4))

console.log(result)
```

A more dynamic version:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const half = arr.length / 2 
const result = arr.slice(half).concat(arr.slice(0, half))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i was just wondering why you used `concat` instead of the spread operator.... the concat method is much better performance wise. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat. Good job :)

Comment: For performance

Comment: @CraigWayne Thank you for your comment.. Checking on the link

Comment: Found this very helpful, now I understand how to move things around. Appreciated!

Comment: @Danyerden Good to help

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method and the [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

First spread the last four elements from the original array and then spread the remaining elements from the beginning.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  newArr = [...arr.slice(-4), ...arr.slice(0, -4)];

console.log(newArr);
```

You can also do it by just using [Array.prototype.Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) but remember it mutates the original array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
arr.splice(0, 0, ...arr.splice(-4));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok mutating the array (rather than creating a new one) [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the last four elements, and then [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) them to the start of the array.

(Note: `splice` returns an array, so you need to [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the elements out.)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
arr.unshift(...arr.splice(-4));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This solution mutates `arr`

Comment: I'm ok with that.

Comment: This is nice +1, I came up with `arr.splice(0, 0, ...arr.splice(-4))`