How to handle state that depends on itself in react
I'm new to react and am having trouble with handling the state for a feature I'm working on.
Feature

let a user draw and edit vertices, that may or may not form polygons.
When a polygon is formed, the user can add some metadata about it.
If an edge splits a polygon in two, the metadata should be "inherited" from the larger polygon.
Metadata should remain through all modifications of the polygon.

Current solution
Here's how I'd like to make this work:

have 4 state items:

vertices [number, number][] A list of x/y coordinate pairs
edges [number, number][] a list of vertex index pairs
polygons {vertices: number[]; metadata: number}[]
A list of objects containing a list of vertex indices and one metadata index
metadata {targetVertices: number[]; data: any}[]
A list of objects containing a list of target vertices and some arbitrary data


when either the edges or the vertices are modified, have a callback do the following:

"solve" polygons from the given edges
for each of the returned "raw" polygons, search for a metadata object whose targetVertices matches (or contains) the polygon's vertices

if a match is found, use this metadata
if no match is found, create an empty metadata object, set its targetVertices to the polygon's vertices, and use that. This is the part that's causing me trouble: I can't do that with useState because i'd need to update the state from a useMemo callback, witch would be a side effect; and I can't do that in a useMemo callback because it "depends on itself" (ie. the callback needs to be aware of the current state of the metadata list to return the proper value of the metadata list)


update the list of "rich" polygons with these polygon+metadata pairs



The algorithm part is done (polygon solving and matching to metadata), but I've been banging my head against react's paradigm to put it all together. I'm pretty sure useEffect would solve my problem, but the official doc advises against it, and I'm trying to do things properly.
Here is a stripped down version of my current code. I've removed a lot of stuff, so be aware that most edge cases are not handled.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Circle, Group, Line, Text } from "react-konva";
import konva from "konva";

import "./App.css";
import { polygonsFromEdges } from "./polygonSolver";

type Vertex = { x: number; y: number; index: number };
type Edge = { vertices: number[]; index: number };

const App = () => {
  const [vertices, setVertices] = React.useState([] as Vertex[]);
  const [edges, setEdges] = React.useState([] as Edge[]);
  const polygons = React.useMemo(getPolygons, [edges, vertices]);
  const [selectedVertex, setSelectedVertex] = useState<number | null>(null);

  function getPolygons() {
    // convert edges and vertices to the format "polygonsFromEdges" expects
    const rawEdges = edges.map((edge) => edge.vertices) as [number, number][];
    const rawVertices = vertices.map((vertex) => [vertex.x, vertex.y]) as [
      number,
      number
    ][];

    // rawPolygons: A list of "polygons" (ordered list of vertex indices)
    const rawPolygons: number[][] = polygonsFromEdges(rawVertices, rawEdges);

    return rawPolygons.map((rawPolygon, idx) => {
      // Convert back to the format "App" expects
      const flatCoordinates = rawPolygon
        .map((vertexId) => [vertices[vertexId].x, vertices[vertexId].y])
        .flat();

      return {
        coordinates: flatCoordinates,
        vertices: rawPolygon,
        index: idx,
      };
    });
  }

  function onClickStage(evt: konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) {
    const clickedOnObject = evt.target.parent !== null;
    if (clickedOnObject) return;

    const vertex = addVertex(evt.evt.x, evt.evt.y);
    if (selectedVertex !== null) {
      addEdge(selectedVertex, vertex.index);
    }
    setSelectedVertex(vertex.index);
  }

  function addVertex(x: number, y: number): Vertex {
    // Side question: How do I make sure this doesn't break if I try to add multiple vertices at once ?
    const vertexIndex = vertices.length;
    const newVertex = { x, y, index: vertexIndex };
    setVertices([...vertices, newVertex]);
    return newVertex;
  }

  function addEdge(vertex1Idx: number, vertex2Idx: number) {
    const newEdge: Edge = {
      vertices: [vertex1Idx, vertex2Idx],
      index: edges.length,
    };
    setEdges(edges.concat(newEdge));
  }

  function onClickVertex(evt: konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) {
    const index = parseInt(evt.currentTarget.id(), 10);
    const clickedVertex = vertices[index];
    if (selectedVertex !== null) {
      addEdge(selectedVertex, clickedVertex.index);
    }

    setSelectedVertex(clickedVertex.index);
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
  }

  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      onClick={onClickStage}
    >
      <Layer>
        {polygons.map((polygon) => (
          <Group key={polygon.index.toString()}>
            <Line points={polygon.coordinates} closed fill="#f005" />
          </Group>
        ))}

        {edges.map((edge) => (
          <Group key={edge.index} id={edge.index.toString()}>
            <Line
              stroke="red"
              strokeWidth={1}
              points={edge.vertices
                .map((vertexIdx) => [
                  vertices[vertexIdx].x,
                  vertices[vertexIdx].y,
                ])
                .flat()}
            />
            <Line
              stroke="#f005"
              strokeWidth={8}
              points={edge.vertices
                .map((vertexIdx) => [
                  vertices[vertexIdx].x,
                  vertices[vertexIdx].y,
                ])
                .flat()}
            />
          </Group>
        ))}

        {vertices.map((vertex) => (
          <Group
            key={vertex.index}
            id={vertex.index.toString()}
            x={vertex.x}
            y={vertex.y}
            onClick={onClickVertex}
          >
            <Text text={`${vertex.index}`} x={15} y={-6} />
            <Circle radius={5} fill="#0f0" />
            <Circle radius={15} fill="#0f05" />
          </Group>
        ))}
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

export default App;


Just a thought, instead of setting states in-sync, you can try emitting a custom event and setting your states there, that way you can access the most current value for your states.

The requirements you listed don't really match the code you provided which makes it difficult to formulate an exact solution, but I'll give you one as per my understanding of the problem.

Convert polygons from useMemo into regular useState. No need to use useMemo for polygons as you'd be recalculating it rather often - useMemo is only for expensive calculations.
Update polygons with some wrapper function whenever you update edges and/or vertices state - using this approach, you can call as many setStates as you want from within the wrapper function. Tip: as the component's state is tightly coupled, you could even update it to utilize useReducer.

Fixed your code to follow these recommendations below:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Circle, Group, Line, Text } from "react-konva";
import konva from "konva";

import "./App.css";
import { polygonsFromEdges } from "./polygonSolver";

type Vertex = { x: number; y: number; index: number };
type Edge = { vertices: number[]; index: number };
type Polygon = { coordinates: number[]; vertices: number[], index: number };

const App = () => {
  const [vertices, setVertices] = React.useState([] as Vertex[]);
  const [edges, setEdges] = React.useState([] as Edge[]);
  const [polygons, setPolygons] = React.useState([] as Polygon[]);
  const [selectedVertex, setSelectedVertex] = useState<number | null>(null);

  function updatePolygons(vertices: Vertex[], edges: Edge[]) {
    // convert edges and vertices to the format "polygonsFromEdges" expects
    const rawEdges = edges.map((edge) => edge.vertices) as [number, number][];
    const rawVertices = vertices.map((vertex) => [vertex.x, vertex.y]) as [
      number,
      number
    ][];

    // rawPolygons: A list of "polygons" (ordered list of vertex indices)
    const rawPolygons: number[][] = polygonsFromEdges(rawVertices, rawEdges);

    // YOU CAN NOW DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THESE POLYGONS, ADD/REMOVE/UPDATE
    const newPolygons = rawPolygons.map((rawPolygon, idx) => {
      // Convert back to the format "App" expects
      const flatCoordinates = rawPolygon
        .map((vertexId) => [vertices[vertexId].x, vertices[vertexId].y])
        .flat();

      return {
        coordinates: flatCoordinates,
        vertices: rawPolygon,
        index: idx,
      };
    });

    setPolygons(newPolygons);
  }

  function onClickStage(evt: konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) {
    const clickedOnObject = evt.target.parent !== null;
    if (clickedOnObject) return;

    const vertex = addVertex(evt.evt.x, evt.evt.y);
    if (selectedVertex !== null) {
      addEdge(selectedVertex, vertex.index);
    }
    setSelectedVertex(vertex.index);
  }

  // THIS IS AN EXAMPLE SOLUTION FOR YOUR SIDE QUESTION
  function addVertices(verticePoints: { x: number; y: number }[]): Vertex[] {
    let index = vertices.length;
    const newVertices = vertices.concat(verticePoints.map((point) => ({ x: point.x, y: point.y, index: index++ })));
    // `concat` is more performant than the spread operator `...` for larger arrays
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat
    setVertices(newVertices);
    updatePolygons(newVertices, edges);
    return newVertices;
  }

  function addVertex(x: number, y: number): Vertex {
    const vertexIndex = vertices.length;
    const newVertex = { x, y, index: vertexIndex };
    const newVertices = [...vertices, newVertex];
    setVertices(newVertices);
    updatePolygons(newVertices, edges);
    return newVertex;
  }

  function addEdge(vertex1Idx: number, vertex2Idx: number) {
    const newEdge: Edge = {
      vertices: [vertex1Idx, vertex2Idx],
      index: edges.length,
    };
    const newEdges = edges.concat(newEdge);
    setEdges(newEdges);
    updatePolygons(vertices, newEdges);
  }

  function onClickVertex(evt: konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) {
    const index = parseInt(evt.currentTarget.id(), 10);
    const clickedVertex = vertices[index];
    if (selectedVertex !== null) {
      addEdge(selectedVertex, clickedVertex.index);
    }

    setSelectedVertex(clickedVertex.index);
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
  }

  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      onClick={onClickStage}
    >
      <Layer>
        {polygons.map((polygon) => (
          <Group key={polygon.index.toString()}>
            <Line points={polygon.coordinates} closed fill="#f005" />
          </Group>
        ))}

        {edges.map((edge) => (
          <Group key={edge.index} id={edge.index.toString()}>
            <Line
              stroke="red"
              strokeWidth={1}
              points={edge.vertices
                .map((vertexIdx) => [
                  vertices[vertexIdx].x,
                  vertices[vertexIdx].y,
                ])
                .flat()}
            />
            <Line
              stroke="#f005"
              strokeWidth={8}
              points={edge.vertices
                .map((vertexIdx) => [
                  vertices[vertexIdx].x,
                  vertices[vertexIdx].y,
                ])
                .flat()}
            />
          </Group>
        ))}

        {vertices.map((vertex) => (
          <Group
            key={vertex.index}
            id={vertex.index.toString()}
            x={vertex.x}
            y={vertex.y}
            onClick={onClickVertex}
          >
            <Text text={`${vertex.index}`} x={15} y={-6} />
            <Circle radius={5} fill="#0f0" />
            <Circle radius={15} fill="#0f05" />
          </Group>
        ))}
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

export default App;


Tip: in your original code, when updating state based on previous state, you should use an updater function.
Instead of:
const [edges, setEdges] = React.useState([] as Edge[]);
// ...
setEdges(edges.concat(newEdge));

Do this instead:
const [edges, setEdges] = React.useState([] as Edge[]);
// ...
setEdges((prevEdges) => prevEdges.concat(newEdge));


Thanks for the answer ! I've thought about calling an update function on each update, but that seems error-prone: I'd prefer to automatically run this function every time edges or vertices are updated, no matter how.

No problem, let us know if this works for you.
